# TDS or GIT question.. how to wipe branches clean in Visual Studio "Team Explorer"

Tags: tds, git

I'd like TDS / GIT / Visual Studio to ignore, forget, delete all my ancient, un-commited work.

And pull a new branch fresh, complete, as if I had a new laptop.

But no, a lot of time spent already and I still have sticky traces of previous interactions. I want and need this out. I was considering deleting the underlying Windows folders but there's got to be an easier way?

Welcoming any help..

Comment: To clarify; these "sticky traces" you refer to - you mean leftover (and now untracked) files in the file system or?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the StackOverflow site

Comment: When you say TDS, do you mean TFS?

Comment: Thank you Mark, I mean branches. And whatever in the background, prevents me to locally delete these.

Thank you Pete, TDS is Team Development for Sitecore, and integrates in GIT / Visual Studio. This is a Sitecore project as a whole, and since I'm not too sure yet which does what (it'll come eventually;) I thought the Sitecore channel to be relevant. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

As a side note, this has nothing to do with Sitecore.

From the git command line, you can can navigate to the repository root and execute this command:

```
git reset --hard
```

Alternatively, you can also do this from Visual Studio:

1. Open the Team Explorer
2. Go to Branches
3. Right click on the currently checked out branch
4. Choose Reset -> Delete Changes

The outcome is the same: all modified, added or untracked files (apart from the files under the `.git` folder) will be deleted.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#git-reset---hard

After you clean up your repository folder, you should of course get the latest version — for that you can use [**`git pull`**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) from the command line, or the Sync tab in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you Dmytro, I believe part of the problem is that my TDS (Team Development for Sitecore) projects under the solution, have been out of sync for a while and maybe part of the issue with GIT.

Comment: ... (continued..) 
When I right click the only 1 left under "Published Branches", I've got the contextual menu: "Switch (greyed-out) - Unpublish Branch - New Branch - Merge... - View History... - Delete (greyed out)

I haven't seen a "Reset -> Delete Changes

I'll try the command line then. Thanks much, awesome precision.. 

YEs it's exactly that, cleaning it all locally, then pulling afresh from our GIT site.